# Can't create a Servlet in eclipse due Path for project must have only one segment

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfNDu.png)

An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Path for project must have only one segment.

facing issue while adding servlet in eclipse

Comment: Can you look in the log, as it directs, to get more details and share them?

Comment: It sure looks like a release older than 2022-06, as well. You should update and retry.

Comment: Image does not show error details.

Answer (score 0):

Create the file in a dynamic project
new -> Dynamic Web Project, I was facing the same issue this cleared it up.
Hope this helps.